# buffer.js Node error with mup deploy - how can i undo ` sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node `

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, buffer

I had an issue deploying a meteor app with mup and got this error:

```
tarted TaskList: Deploy app 'thermaMup' (linux)
[107.170.77.189] - Uploading bundle
[107.170.77.189] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[107.170.77.189] - Setting up Environment Variables
[107.170.77.189] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[107.170.77.189] - Invoking deployment process
[107.170.77.189] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/opt/thermaMup/tmp/bundle/programs/server)
    stop: Unknown instance: 
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    App did not pick up! Please check app logs.
```

My logs read

```
[107.170.77.189] error: Script restart attempt #150[107.170.77.189] 
[107.170.77.189] Meteor requires Node v0.10.41 or later.[107.170.77.189]
```

And I've been able to solve this problem on my separate laptop by changing my mup.json file to have a longer `deployCheckWaitTime`, and a different `nodeVersion`.  BUT, I had alreadly run these commands on my desktop:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
 sudo n stable
 sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

And now the error I'm seeing on my desktop since is:

```
Building Started: .
buffer.js:106
      throw new Error(
      ^

Error: If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:106:13)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/archiver/lib/util/index.js:32:15)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

How do I *undo* those previous sudo commands?  Should I just uninstall and reinstall node completely?

Comment: I seemed to have fixed this by installing node 4.4.3 instead of 6.0.0 https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed this by installing node 4.4.3 instead of 6.0.0 github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2825

Answer (score 1):

I have installed `Node v8.10.0` made one change in the following file in my

> node_modules\node_modules\archiver\lib\util\index.js

```js
source.on('end', function() {
    //(may be different for few) Line 32: 
    // updated this line and add +'' in the first param to make it as string argument 
    var buf = new Buffer(size+'', 'utf8'); 

    var offset = 0;

    collection.forEach(function(data) {
        data.copy(buf, offset);
        offset += data.length;
    });
});
```

I hope this helps